# How to recognize which link is clicked with JSX. - React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a lot of `<a href />`.
I would like to recognize which link is clicked.

```
    onClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("CLICK!!" + e);
    }

    render(){
      <a key={member.id} className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>
        {member.name}
      </a>
    }
```

How can I do for it? 
Thanks.

Comment: @ajihiro do you have multiple links?

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar  Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<a href onClick={evt => { this.onClick("a_1", evt)}}/>

onClick(name, evt) {
    switch (name) {
        case "a_1":
            // ...
            break;
        case "a_2":
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get second parameter e in onClick function.